# Brackets are not included as Code Coverage for Unit Tests c# in VSO

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, xunit

There are some code coverage inconsistencies between the VSO build pipeline and Visual Studio local. We found that the code coverage in Visual Studio is higher because it counts brackets as part of the code coverage. But it doesnt count in VSO build pipeline for some reason. Anyone knows why? Is this a known bug in VSO?

We use Xunit and c# for the tests and have test.runsettings to exclude code. Below is the test.runsettings file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
  <!-- Configurations that affect the Test Framework -->
  <RunConfiguration>
    <!-- Path relative to directory that contains .runsettings file-->
    <ResultsDirectory>.\TestResults</ResultsDirectory>
    <TargetPlatform>x64</TargetPlatform>
    <MaxCpuCount>10000</MaxCpuCount>
  </RunConfiguration>

  <!-- Configurations for data collectors -->
  <DataCollectionRunSettings>
    <DataCollectors>
      <DataCollector friendlyName="Code Coverage" uri="datacollector://Microsoft/CodeCoverage/2.0" assemblyQualifiedName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.DynamicCoverageDataCollector, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TraceCollector, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
        <Configuration>
          <CodeCoverage>
     <Attributes>
              <Exclude>
                <Attribute>^System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.ExcludeFromCodeCoverageAttribute$</Attribute>
              </Exclude>
            </Attributes>
            <ModulePaths>
             <Exclude>
                <ModulePath>.*unittests.dll$</ModulePath>
                <ModulePath>.*integrationtests.dll$</ModulePath>
                <ModulePath>.*xunit.*.dll</ModulePath>
                <ModulePath>.*fluentassertions.*$</ModulePath>
                <ModulePath>.*moq.*$</ModulePath>
                <ModulePath>.*telemetry.extensions.ai.netcore.*$</ModulePath>
                <ModulePath>.*newtonsoft.*$</ModulePath>
                <ModulePath>.*codeanalysis.*$</ModulePath>
              </Exclude>
            </ModulePaths>

            <!-- We recommend you do not change the following values: -->
            <UseVerifiableInstrumentation>True</UseVerifiableInstrumentation>
            <AllowLowIntegrityProcesses>True</AllowLowIntegrityProcesses>
            <CollectFromChildProcesses>True</CollectFromChildProcesses>
            <CollectAspDotNet>False</CollectAspDotNet>

          </CodeCoverage>
        </Configuration>
      </DataCollector>
</DataCollectors>
</DataCollectionRunSettings>
</RunSettings>
```

Comment: Do you use the same test adapters in local and DevOps? Could you share how did you configure your DevOps pipeline? Also, could you share detailed log in VS and DevOps? If possible, please provide a sample project so that we can reproduce your scenario.

Comment: Any update to this issue?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT thanks and I will update my answer below. The issue is fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it's showing inconsistent code coverage is because in Visual Studio, I was running Debug mode instead of Release mode. After changing it to Release mode, the number is consistent to the VSO number.